# View image in the image field of the php 

Tags: php, image, sql-server-2008, view

Good day!

Could anyone help me, there is a system where users do register via their desktop in a database hosted on the web, we are now developing the web interface of this system, then it has a certain functionality in the system where I have to display the photo user.

I do what normal SELECT in SQL Server, but upon the imagejpeg ($ img); it does not show the whole picture, just a piece of the picture. Could anyone help me? I'm looking for some tutorials on the web and they speak it is because of the size of the field. If the field is of type (image) and the return is in hexadecimal.

Below I tried to do a function with the help of a friend, but she also did not work:

```
<php
 $id     = (int)$_GET['id'];
 $qryimg = mssql_query(gimage SELECT FROM user WHERE id = {$ id});
 $resimg = mssql_fetch_array($qryimg);
 $im1    = $resimg['gimage'];

 header("Content-type: image/jpg");

 $image='';
 for($i=2; $i<strlen($im1); $i+=2)
 {
     $hex = $im1{$i} . $im1{($i + 1)};
     $cod = hexdec( $hex );
     $image .= chr( $cod );
 }
 echo $image;
 #echo imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't the following code work? Can't you just echo the image.

```
<php
 $id     = (int)$_GET['id'];
 $qryimg = mssql_query(gimage SELECT FROM user WHERE id = {$ id});
 $resimg = mssql_fetch_array($qryimg);
 $im1    = $resimg['gimage'];

 header("Content-type: image/jpg");

 print $im1;
 exit;
```

What field type is gimage?

Comment: Hello, thanks for trying to help me.

The field gimage is the field name. Thus giving a print $ im1; not the right direct. Keeps popping up just a piece of the picture. field image returns a string in a hexadecimal 4000bytes.

+ - Like this example:
0xFH3H09800000111 ........

Comment: You didn't answer my question. what TYPE is gimate. By the looks of it, it looks like it's a VARCHAR or CHAR. It needs to be a type BLOB. When you print it, you should not get hexadecimal numbers. If you have no control over how it's stored, then perhaps it's not your fault and the image storer is storing only half the image. 

Play with a smaller sized image. Does it work? then it's the field size limiting you.

Comment: Hello the field is of type IMAGE (SQL SERVER 2008), the image is being stored correctly as I've tried 4 different users log on and 4 present the same problem. I can not change the threshold of the image because it already has quite a number of records registered and desktop systems running on multiple clients, not to rebuild these systems: (

I'm trying to find something on the internet and find nothing about it, some say they have to break the string into several pieces, but I have no idea what to do.

thank you